# How to acces className to hide a Raphael path, works in Chrome, not in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, raphael

I have this code to apply a class to a raphael svg path:

```
if ( ! ( $.browser.msie)){
    obj.node.setAttribute('class','statepath');
}else{
obj.node.setAttribute('className','statepath');
}
```

IE accepts the property className but no class, therefore, the markup ends up something like this

```
className = 'statepath' in IE
class = 'statepath' in good browsers
```

I am trying to hide all paths and animate the one clicked. I can achieve this by using this event

```
obj.click(function(){
    //document.getElementsByClassName('statepath').(Element.hide); -- not working
$('.statepath').hide();  // works on Good Browsers      
});
```

This las code works only on good browsers but in IE does not. Does this have to do with the attribute className that jquery can not access to or to something else?

Comment: Try this: obj.node.className = 'statepath'

Comment: Thanks Alexey but I already tried it and does not seem to work

Answer (score 1):

Rapahel uses SVG for almost all browsers, and fall back to VML on IE. That might explain why the `hide()` call is not working, jQuery may not be able to hide a VML element.

Have you tried the Raphael `hide()` method? http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.hide

Comment: I tried to but i dont know how to get all paths except the one clicked. Do you have any suggestions? Thank you so mucho for your answer

Comment: try to use Raphael's `set` (this is an abstraction of an array), and bind events to the set - which will bind to all contained items.